# While using glassfish, unable to call jersey's root-resource with a constructor with inject-able parameters

Tags: jersey, glassfish, jax-rs, cdi, jersey-2.0

The REST-API project is working fine when Tomcat ver 7.0.92 is used. But when the project is run on Glassfish ver 5.1.0 server with same set of libraries, it produces the following exception:

```
[2020-02-04T11:33:43.143+0500] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(13)] [timeMillis: 1580798023143] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 1
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.CreationException: WELD-001530: Cannot produce an instance of class tempJersey.TempEP.
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.NonProducibleInjectionTarget.produce(NonProducibleInjectionTarget.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier$2.getInstance(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier._provide(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.GenericCdiBeanSupplier.get(GenericCdiBeanSupplier.java:42)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.provide(InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.java:53)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:46)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:754)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:717)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:245)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

]]

[2020-02-04T11:33:43.145+0500] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(13)] [timeMillis: 1580798023145] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[tempRest]: Servlet.service() for servlet tempRest threw exception
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.CreationException: WELD-001530: Cannot produce an instance of class tempJersey.TempEP.
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.NonProducibleInjectionTarget.produce(NonProducibleInjectionTarget.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier$2.getInstance(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanSupplier._provide(AbstractCdiBeanSupplier.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.GenericCdiBeanSupplier.get(GenericCdiBeanSupplier.java:42)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.provide(InstanceSupplierFactoryBridge.java:53)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.create(FactoryCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:463)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:46)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2102)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:754)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:717)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.AbstractHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(AbstractHk2InjectionManager.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.getInstance(ImmediateHk2InjectionManager.java:30)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:105)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:86)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:69)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:38)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:245)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]
```

Following is the sample code I am trying to run:

```
package tempJersey;


import com.forwardyou.filosservice.core.common.controller.UserController;
import com.forwardyou.filosservice.endpoints.RestFilosBaseEndPoint;
import com.forwardyou.securitymanager.core.common.dto.UserDTO;
import com.forwardyou.securitymanager.util.ApplicationConstants;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import fiscal.bean.FiscalValidationBean;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Path("/common")
public class TempEP extends RestFilosBaseEndPoint {


    public TempEP(@QueryParam("urlCode") String urlCode) {
        super(new UserController(null,null,null));
    }


    @GET
    @Path("basicget")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response logGET(@QueryParam(value = "str") String reqStr) {

        return Response.ok(reqStr).build();

    }


    @POST
    @Path("userform")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response logPOST(
            @FormParam(value = "name") String reqName,
            @FormParam(value = "pwd") String reqPwd,
            @FormParam(value = "roles") List<String>roles

    ) {
        LinkedHashMap<String,Object> userInfo = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        userInfo.put("Name",reqName);
        userInfo.put("Password",reqPwd);
        userInfo.put("roles",roles);

        return Response.ok(new Gson().toJson(userInfo)).build();

    }

}
```

Following libraries are also used in the depoloyed application

1. Swagger 1.5.21
2. Jersey  2.29.1

When a no-arg constructor is added in root-resource class, the class starts responding the requests. The problem is that the whole rest-project is based on  the following assumption of jersey-documentation

[image]

[Documentation Link](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2763)

Kindly provide some guidance?

Answer (score 2):

You are running into the fact that Jersey has its own dependency injection system, HK2 in this case, but must also, in order to be Java EE-compliant, be able to run in a larger environment where CDI (Weld) is the dependency injection system.  In your case, you are now trying to run your program in such an environment (Glassfish).

So while *Jersey's* rules of injection are correct, and you have obeyed them, these are not necessarily CDI's rules of injection.  You have not obeyed those.

In this case, CDI doesn't know how to "make" a `@QueryParam("urlCode") String urlCode`, nor should it.  Additionally, CDI does not see any constructor annotated with `@Inject` whose parameters are things it can "make", and finally CDI doesn't see [its last possible fallback, a zero-argument constructor](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/cdi-spec-2.0.html#instantiation).

When you add the zero-argument constructor, CDI is happy and knows how to instantiate and manage the `TempEP` class.

If you read the stack trace carefully, you can see where HK2 "hands off" injection responsibility to CDI—and where CDI discovers that it doesn't know how to "make" a `TempEP` instance.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Laird. So you are saying that a zero-arg constructor is mandatory to run the application on Glassfish. Is there anyway to use JARs other than provided with glassfish, to run the application.